# Magento - Add URL key in my module (URL rewriting)

Tags: magento, url, key

I want to add a "URL key" field in my module so as to have a formatted URL.
ex:
I want this
"www.mywebsite.com/station/station_name/zip_code/city"

instead of
"www.mywebsite.com/station?id=8&name=station_name"

Thank you for helping me, I look without finding anything on the web

Sorry for my english, I'm french...

Answer (score 0):

**Custom router in Magento**

you have to implement routers in your module. for the url you looking for. here is complete tutorial : http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-router-in-magento/